# Finding probability of bivariate normal distribution?

Tags: normal-distribution, descriptive-statistics, bivariate

Okay so I am having some trouble with this problem. Let's say two variables G and C jointly follow bivariate normal distribution. With G having mean 480 and SD 100 and C having mean 320 and SD 60. Now I can solve problem like P(G < 360) or P(G - C < 400). What I'm having trouble on is P(G = 400). How do I find the probability that a variable is equal to something when it follows this distribution? T

Answer (score 0):

Are you perhaps asking about conditional probability?

With continuous RVs, $P(X=k)=0$.  If you ask about one RV in a joint distribution, that doesn't really make things different.

Comment: See I had problems that asked about conditional probability in this assignment and I was able to solve those. I was just confused on this question because of the fact it asked me P(X=k). Is there a way to solve P(X=k) if it were just one random variable that is normally distributed?

Comment: Ignore the joint distribution.  Imagine a single RV.  Now imagine that you have a circle that goes from 0 to 1, with an arrow you can spin in the middle (sort of like a roulette wheel).  The probability distribution would, in that case, be a uniform distribution when you spin the arrow: it lands anywhere with equal chance.  Now - and this is a bit hard mathematically - the probability of any single number coming up on a spin (like $\sqrt \pi /10$ is zero.  the probability it lies between, say, 0 and 0.5 is 50%.  It will land on a number, but the probability of that number is zero.  Follow?

Comment: Yeah I believe I understand it now, Thank you for your help.

Comment: You are more than welcome.